# Assign Identifier if Conditions Met

Tags: python, pandas, loops, multiple-conditions

I have df1 with latitude and longitude data for each observation and df2 that contains latitude and longitude buckets that together capture every possible combination. df2 also includes a column containing a unique "bucket ID" for each bucket. I want to create a column in df1 that is filled with the correct bucket ID for each observation.

df1

```
      | Latitude | Longitude
0     | 36.9003  | 98.2183
1     | 33.1701  | 98.2988
...   | ...      | ...
2999  | 39.8944  | 98.2018
3000  | 34.9582  | 100.0900
```

df2

```
      | Lat_Start | Lat_End | Long_Start | Long_End | Bucket_ID
0     | 33.10     | 33.15   | 98.20      | 98.25    | 0
1     | 33.16     | 33.20   | 98.26      | 98.30    | 1
...   | ...       | ...     | ...        | ...      | ...
76699 | 39.96     | 40.00   | 100.01     | 100.05   | 76699
76700 | 40.01     | 40.05   | 100.06     | 100.10   | 76700
```

Expected Output
df1

```
      | Latitude | Longitude | Bucket_ID
0     | 36.9003  | 98.2183   | 34053
1     | 33.1701  | 98.2988   | 1
...   | ...      | ...       | ...
2999  | 39.8944  | 98.2018   | 65382
3000  | 34.9582  | 100.0900  | 3244
```

Comment: Can you expand you df1 & df2 with a few more rows & show the expected output as well (using the data that you provide).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, moys. I have added another example row in the existing dfs and have added an example of the expected output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since your dataset seems to be not very large, this simple(however inefficient) piece of code may help you solve the problem:

```
def find_bucket(latitude, longitude):
    for i in df2.index:
        if df2['Lat_Start'].loc[i]<=latitude and df2['Lat_End'].loc[i]>=latitude and df2['Long_Start'].loc[i]<=longitude and df2['Long_End'].loc[i]>=longitude:
            return df2['Bucket_ID'].loc[i]
    return -1

df1['Bucket_ID'] = df1.apply(lambda x: find_bucket(x.loc['Latitude'], x.loc['Longitude']), axis = 1)
```